# What to do about comments with broken MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax, comment, editing

Sometimes one comes across content that has MathJax that does not render correctly. When it is a post one can edit it.

But what to do about comments that have MathJax that does not render correctly or at all?

Is there any way to fix broken comments?

Comment: I will add also a link to the older discussion where the MathJax overflowing into the right margin makes it difficult for the author of the comment to edit or to delete the comment: [Should I flag comments, where long MathJax breaks page layout?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13700) Although if the only issue is that the poster cannot find edit/delete button, some workarounds how to deal with this without help of moderators have been suggested. ...

Comment: ... See, for example, [My comments got stretched across the screen, and it won't allow me to edit or delete the comment either.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24987) or [Comments layout break if Math expression is too long](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2652) and other [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2652).

Answer (score 10):

Moderators can edit comments. Thus, if one comes across a broken comment one can flag the comment "something else" and point out that there is broken formatting and request a fix.

This is perfectly acceptable and we usually will try to do what we can to restore the comment.

However, please, do not flood us with such request. Instead, focus on things you come across naturally where there is something relevant to be fixed. 
Problems that break the layout of the site or impede comprehending the comment are among the most urgent.

At the very moment there is a fair number of such comments around as there was a change regarding the scope of macros. We are aware of various recurring issues. ¨Please do not run a  search and flag up all instances of something. If there is a recurring issue that you think needs to be addressed, please, raise it in general terms not via individual flags cast in bunch.

Comment: Since you have mentioned also the comments where this was caused by recent changes in the software (and which were rendered fine before the the scope of macro definitions was changed from the whole page to separate posts), I will add a link to a [related conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64952/conversation/problems-in-posts-and-comments-added-by-automated-adding-of-begingroup-endgrou) and also to a [separate chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/88939/2019/1/29) where I have tried to find some ways how to find posts and comments influenced by this change.