# Improved wrong comments written with MathJaX?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax, comment, editing

Sometimes I see that some comments are written with command or syntax errors.

In fact they are displayed in **red** (for example $\gama$ instead of `\gamma` ($\gamma$)) because the command or symbol used is not the correct. I think the only solution is to write a comment to the user to delete it and to write a new comment with the correct syntax. If there are other solutions they are well appreciated.

Comment: flag for moderation ...

Comment: Related: [What to do about comments with broken MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29852)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I have understood. Hence, with lot of sincerity my question is a duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because I have solved my question by comment of an user that I have indicated the best link https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29852